# hide "from" by default in new mail

Tags: microsoft-outlook-365

I had an Office Update a few days ago (now on Version 2302 Build 16130.20644, 64 bit) and since then "from" field appears by default when I start a new email.

Before that it was not the case, is there any way to hide it by default?

### edit 1

I've tried editing registry and restarting outlook as suggested, however it doesn't seem to solve the issue.

[image]

Comment: I assume temporarily downgrading your installation isn’t an option to verify a different change on the Exchange side of the house wasn’t also performed is out of the question?

Comment: indeed, unfortunately I can't downgrade my Office.

Comment: Outlook is now 2306 but in any event, there is not a way to hide the from field.

Comment: Just to make sure: If you click “New Email”, then go to the “Options” ribbon and deselect “From” there, the field will appear anyway when you click “New Email” again, right?

Comment: @DanielB interestingly when I click "new email" it doesn't appear, only when I reply to / forward an existing one. Yes, I've deselected "from" several times and it still keeps appearing.

Answer (score 1):

This will theoretically work :

- Run `regedit`
- Navigate to the key:
  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\DisabledCmdBarItemsList`
- Create a new DWORD item called `TCID1` and give it the value `1867`
- Start Outlook.

The value `1867` can be found in the spreadsheet
[CommandID2003.xls](https://www.howto-outlook.com/files/CommandID2003.xls)
in line 101.

If you wish to add more entries, call the next ones `TCID2` and
following.

Comment: sorry, I'm not familiar with regedit, I have `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook` there, but not `DisabledCmdBarItemsList`

Comment: When positioned to that registry key, right-click any empty space on the right part and select *New > DWORD (32-bit)*. Rename the new key to `TCID1` and double-click it to set its value to `1867`.

Comment: it doesn't seem to work :( (see screenshot in question)

Comment: AFAIK that's the only known registry entry for doing that. If it stopped working in Outlook 365, then I'm not sure that a solution does exist for your question.